# How to Adapter TextView?

Tags: android, textview, adapter, drawable

I have an adapter which takes items from Drawable and put them into a GridView. The adapter works great with Drawables. However, I'm in need of getting TextViews from Layout instead of Drawables.

This works great with Drawable:

```
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.carrot, R.drawable.emerald,
        R.drawable.turquoise, R.drawable.greensea,
    };
```

However, I tried simply changing the items paths to the ID's of the TextViews:

```
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.id.text_test,R.id.text_test,
        R.id.text_test,R.id.text_test,      
    };
```

The app runs fine but I don't see the TextViews, instead the GridView appears, however with items filled with nothing. The adapter seems to be able to import the TextViews as they are clickable, however without any content.

What am I missing out?

My XML for the TextView:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:background="#ff0000"/>

</GridLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

**ImageAdapter:**

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

private int mItemHeight = 300;

// set photo item height
public void setItemHeight(int height) {
    if (height == mItemHeight) {
        return;
    }
    mItemHeight = height;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;



    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mItemHeight));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.carrot, R.drawable.emerald,
        R.drawable.turquoise, R.drawable.greensea,
        R.drawable.nephritis, R.drawable.peterriver,
        R.drawable.carrot, R.drawable.emerald,
        R.drawable.turquoise, R.drawable.greensea,
        R.drawable.nephritis, R.drawable.peterriver,
        R.drawable.carrot, R.drawable.emerald,
        R.drawable.turquoise, R.drawable.greensea,
        R.drawable.nephritis, R.drawable.peterriver,



};
}
```

I tried to change the ImageView to TextView instead changing it to this. However, it now returns "false" in every view in the GridView. Am I getting close?

**TextView Adapter:**

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    TextView textView;


    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        textView = new TextView(mContext);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(300, 300));
        //textView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        textView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    } else {
        textView = (TextView) convertView;
    }

    textView.setText(mThumbIds[position]);
    return textView;
}

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.id.text_test,R.id.text_test,
        R.id.text_test,R.id.text_test,
        R.id.text_test,R.id.text_test,
        R.id.text_test,R.id.text_test,

};

}
```

Comment: you are just importing the views of text views and not their content. i think you need an array of string using getText and then send this to your adapter

Comment: so actually what is mThumbIds for?

Comment: Please see the updated code where I show the ImageAdapter and the TextViewAdapter I'm trying to get to work. Am I getting close?

Answer (score 0):

AFAK, you want to set the backgroud for each item in the grid layout.
So the background should be an image (drawable) than the text.
setBackgroud or setText...
May be you should upload your code in adapater here

Comment: I want to display TextViews containing a text and a background. As shapes in drawable doesn't allow text, I have to achieve this via TextViews with backgrounds and texts, am I right? Please see my updated post including the adapters.

Comment: Yes, your approach is close to the solution.
    `textView.setText`
here, you set the text for the textView only
If you want to set backgroud, please call textView.setBackgroundResource()
one more thing is R.id.text_test... If you want to set background, save the drawable in res/drawable folder and then define them as 
    `private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.xxxx `

Comment: Why do I get "false" as text in my GridView from the TextView when doing textView.setText(mThumbIds[position])? Shouldn't it return the text "Hello World!" from my .XML? Do you mean it's not possible do get the whole TextView (background + text) at once, or do I have to separate them with first getting background and then getting text?

Comment: I see that you got some issues about this.
textView.setText() it got an string to display, but you parse an integer instead of :)
in the example, they use setImageResource(int id) to fetch the drawable from id resource.
See the example code below
  textView.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(mThumbIds[position]));
  textView.setBackground(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(mThumbId[position]));
return textView;
You should uses getResource() to load the resource into your view :D